# How do I determine if Anonymous Access is enabled in IIS 6 using PowerShell?

Tags: iis-6, powershell-2.0

I hve several IIS 6 web sites that I need to survey. One of the items that I need to check is AllowAnonymous. I need to know if it is True or False. I found this bit of code:

```
$a = gwmi -Namespace root\MicrosoftIISv2 -Class IIsWebServerSetting -ComputerName
$ServerName -Impersonation Impersonate -Authentication PacketPrivacy |
Select-object AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous
```

That gives me this:

```
PS> $a | gm


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject

Name                          MemberType   Definition
----                          ----------   ----------
Equals                        Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode                   Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType                       Method       type GetType()
ToString                      Method       string ToString()
AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous NoteProperty  AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous=null
```

How do I get the NoteProperty into a variable for my report?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to infer that you already know how to read the value of a property of an object by adding a `.` and the property name, but you're running into difficulties with this oddly-named property because if you assign `$a.AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous` to a variable, the value is always null.

The reason is that the property name contains a dot, which is the property/method operator. So, PowerShell doesn't interpret `$a.AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous` as "read the **AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous** property of the object **$a**; it interprets it as "read the **AllowAnonymous** property of the object contained in the **AllowAnonymous** property of **$a**. In other words, it first evaluates **$a.AllowAnonymous** (which is null, because **$a** doesn't have a property named **AllowAnonymous**), and then attempts to read the **AllowAnonymous** property of the null result, which is of course also null.

The solution is simple. Quote the property name:

```
$SomeVariable = $a.'AllowAnonymous.AllowAnonymous'
```